# Mapboxgl draw click events do not show precise points

Tags: mapbox-gl-draw

I have implemented Mapboxgl draw on my project, on the desktop view, click events track points correctly and places point exactly where I click, but on the mobile view, the points appear a bit further away from where users click

I tried figuring out how the points are added on the map after clicks, but don't know how the drawing is happening exactly just followed documentation. Also, I didn't write code from scratch

Answer (score 0):

The discrepancy might be due to device resolution and touch events on mobile. Check viewport settings and test on various devices.